# What does the comma mean in this equation for measuring strength of season and trend?

Tags: notation

I am not familiar with the use of commas as seen in this equation for strength of season and trend:

Given, $$y_t = T_t + S_{t} + R_t,$$
Where $y_t$ is the forecast at time $_t$, $T$ is trend, $S$ is seasonality, and $R$ is error,

$$F_T = \max\left(0, 1 - \frac{\text{Var}(R_t)}{\text{Var}(T_t+R_t)}\right)$$

What does the $0,1$ mean in this notation?

##### References

[Measuring strength of trend and seasonality](https://otexts.com/fpp2/seasonal-strength.html#seasonal-strength)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mistyped the equation a bit, firstly:

$$F_{T} = \max\Biggl(0,1- \frac{\mathrm{Var}(R_t)}{\mathrm{Var}(T_t + R_t)}\Biggl)$$

Generally,

$$\max(a,b) = \begin{cases}
a & \text{if } a \ge b\\
b & \text{if } a \le b
\end{cases}$$

More simply "take whichever value is bigger". In this case, it might be done in order to ensure that $F_T \ge 0$ always, for instance. So that means that

$$F_T = 0 \text{ or } F_T = 1- \frac{\mathrm{Var}(R_t)}{\mathrm{Var}(T_t + R_t)}$$

whichever quantity is larger.

Comment: Thanks for catching that error, I updated my question. Is this saying, "F_{T} must be no greater than 0 AND no greater than 1"?

Comment: I wouldn't know because I don't know what the variables in this question represent. If 

$$0 < \mathrm{Var}(R_t) \le \mathrm{Var}(T_t + R_t)$$

for instance, then, sure.